# C# DateTime with MongoDb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm trying to parse DateTime as Json to MongoDB.

This is my Post Request via Json :

```
    {
      "birthdate": "2022-05-19T19:27:44.952Z"
    }
```

This is the part of my C# class:

```
public  DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
```

However in the MongoDB it is stored like this:

```
0001-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00
```

But this works:

```
public  DateTime Birthdate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now
```

however I want to store a custom DateTime

Comment: How are you handling the object you get in your controller?

Comment: Apparently that was the fix. I didn't pass it to the Database

Answer (score 0):

There’s not really enough information here to give a complete answer, but in the console you would need to wrap the string in an ISODate.

```
{
  "birthdate": new ISODate("2022-05-19T19:27:44.952Z")
}
```

See:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/Date/